# "SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server] Invalid 'users' object name

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I migrated my MySQL database to SQL Server 2019.

I made the required configurations:

```php
php.ini

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64

.env

DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=servername
DB_PORT=null
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

The code below is working fine. O test this in web.php and i get db connect successfully and all (2) tables.

```php
 try {
        DB::connection()->getPdo();
        echo DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()."  db connect successfully";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }
    $sql = DB::select("SELECT  TOP (2) id, email, email_verified_at, password, remember_token, image, userable_id, userable_type, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at FROM soraeir.users", [1]);
    die(print_r($sql));
```

Message when I try to login I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
> Invalid 'users' object name. (SQL: select top 1 * from [users] where [email] = admin and [users].[deleted_at] is null)"

I think eloquent must add an instance_name to all queries...I don't know how to proceed...?

Perhaps, instead of

```sql
select top 1 *
from [users]
where [email] = admin
  and [users].[deleted_at] is null
```

We could use

```sql
select top 1 * 
from [instance_name].[users]
where [email] = admin
and [users].[deleted_at] is null
```

Comment: If the SQL in your PHP is referencing an object that doesn't exist, the error should be `Invalid object name 'soraeir.users'.` as you are schema qualifying the object this suggests that the code you've given us and the error you've given us aren't related.

Comment: Also `FROM [instance_name].[users]` wouldn't be written like that. To include the instance name in the object path you would need to use 4 part naming: `[Instance name].[Database Name].[Schema Name].[Object Name]`. As you should be directly connected to the database your object is in, you only need 2 part naming, `[Schema Name].[Object Name]`, which is what you appear to have in your query.

Comment: Also note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: Finally, the fact you have a column called `password` and no salt column really smells like you are storing plain text passwords; I *really* hope you aren't.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu for your answer ... i didn't use plain text passwords

Comment: I think my problem is with laravel queries (eloquent or sqlsrv pdo )... when I test manually I can insert, select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved my problem**

my problem was when I was doing the migration I misconfigured at the level of schema mapping with **sql server migration assistant for mysql**.

all my tables in sql server db was : **mysql_db_name.table_name**

**Solution**

**Source Schema**: mysql_db_name

**Target Schema** : sqlsrv_db_name.**dbo**

**dbo** is required

now all tables are as follows : dbo.table_name